# Player Sprite keeps slipping in Sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    let positionInScene = touch!.location(in: self)
    let touchedNode = self.atPoint(positionInScene)

    if let name = touchedNode.name {
        if name == "jumpbutton" && isReady == true {
            isReady = false
            
            let boost = SKAction.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 300.0), duration: 0.1)
            
            
            touchedNode.run(buttonPressAction)
            player?.run(boost)
            
            let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.2)
                           run(wait) { [self] in
                             isReady = true
                           }
                print("jumpbutton")
            }
```

I understand this is very vague but my player sprite just randomly starts gradually slipping either to the right or the left for no apparent reason. It is especially prevalent when I apply a vertical impulse as shown above. Any insight or help is appreciated. Also the body type is bounding rectangle as it seems to happen less than when it is alpha mask or bounding circle.

Comment: I would check that the node the player is resting on is not rotated slightly, and that it is also a bounding rectangle. Set physicsbody.allowrotation to false on the player and ground. If this happens when the player is idle, you could create a function where if no buttons are pressed and the playerr should just be standing still, you could set its velocity to 0 (this is a bit of workaround, as the underlying cause of issue i guess would remain). There is also physicsBody.friction, you could change this value.

Comment: No problem. If/When you have solved the issue it would be good to put the solution in an answer so that it helps someone else in future.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my images were not cropped correctly and therefore caused my player sprite to slip.